# Objective-C checks if array with ints contains int

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, int

Folks, I'm trying to do the following.
I've got a array (NSArray) called 'specialLevels', that array looks like this:

```
specialLevels = @[@2, @4, @6, @9];
```

This should be a array of int's. 
I also got the int 'currentLevel' (basic int no object).

And I want to check if the currentLevel is in de array of specialLevels.
I know the method 'containsObject' exists, but this won't work in my case.

What would you guys recommend to do in this case?

So I thought this, but it feels kinda strange imo:

```
if ([specialLevels containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentLevel]]) {
 // other code in here
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? You don't like the line of code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

specialLevels is not an array of ints. It is an array of NSNumber objects. @2, @4, @6, @8 each create an NSNumber instance equivalent to calling [[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]. When you call containsObject you also need to pass an NSNumber object so that containsObject can match the value (using isEqual:).

You can read about [Objective-C literals here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Answer (score 22):

You could alternatively write:

```
if ([specialLevels containsObject:@(currentLevel)]) {
    // other code in here
}
```

which is more in keeping with the style of your other code.

Comment: Awesome, indeed thanks! But how is this valid, any documentation about this?

Comment: Did you understand what `@2` was doing before you started using it? The answer from @BrianWalker is a good overview.

Comment: No I didn't, but now I do, thanks for that explanation! Clear for me now :)